# Agm info window custom css

Tags: css, angular, google-maps, agm-map

I have created a agm-info-window that has an image and a small text (tittle):

```
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat3" [longitude]="lng3" [iconUrl]="icon">
    <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true" [isOpen]="true">
        <div routerLink="/sight/2">
            <img src="assets/mesta/tvrdjava.jpg" alt="Image" width="80" height="80"> <br>
            <span class="window-title"> Bubanj </span>
        </div>
    </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```

This is the result:

[image]

**I want to change the info window css.** - The background color, remove the close button (x) and put the text in the center. Like so:

[image]

I get the correct effect when I set the CSS in Chrome's inspector. I set:

```
/* Remove the X, close button */
.gm-ui-hover-effect {
    display: none;
}

.gm-style-iw {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* remove overflow scroll */
.gm-style-iw-d {
    overflow: none;
}
```

But when I put this same css in the components css, it doesn't change at all, nothing changes.

I don't have a lot of changes, so I would prefer not to use snazzy info window. I just want these small changes to the window. Is it possible ? Why is the css not working ?

Comment: Did you try with `!important` to css properties?

Comment: Yep, tried it, nothing. @Kenny

Comment: @Kenny using !Important is not good practice

Comment: Try adding this css in global styles of angular instead of component css

Comment: And make sure the stylesheet is actually embeded and comes last (to make sure it's not overriden by something else)

Comment: I added the css to the global styles.css, nothing changes. Like it get overwritten somehow. @Sonia

Comment: @TimGerhard How can I make sure that it comes last ? I tried adding to global style.css, nothing.

Comment: Well usually !important overrides the styles anyway, no matter if they're first or last. It seems like your stylesheet is not embedded. Try using your browser inspection tools. can you find your css code that you added anywhere? Does other css work?

Comment: Try adding the CSS within a <style></style> tag inside the <agm-info-window> tag

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS in styles.css as component css is having low priorities
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css in he same page under the div. Maybe there are cinflict b/w that's why it doesn't change anything.